# Harvest yield farming - how do some assets have 10k+ APY?

Tags: liquidity-provider, staking

[image]

Currently there are some assets on [harvest.finance](https://harvest.finance/) with crazy apy rates. How is this possible? Are these scams?

Comment: That question is not suited for that forum. That being said, new yield farms tend to have a very high APY/APR because the reward token is overpriced (its supply will go up without its market cap following as rewards are minted) and there's usually not much money in the pools (so you get a bigger share of the pools rewards).

Answer (score 0):

> How do some assets have 10k+ APY?

Because they are scams, one way or another.